# vector space differential operator(ker) (image) (rank) (nullity)

Tags: vector-spaces, differential

Let V = Rn[x], the vector space of polynomials of degree <= n. Define D : V → V to be differentiation with respect to X. Find the rank and the nullity of D.

how to find the kernel of the differential operator? I think the dimension of the ker is supposed to be n. and the image, is it also n?

Comment: What polynomials **exactly** are mapped to the zero polynomial? Or in other words: for what kind of polynomials is their derivative zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encoding the polynomials as coordinate vectors
$$
p_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n c_{k+1} x^k \\
c = (c_k) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \\
e(p) = c
$$
e.g.
$$
p(x) = 2 x^3 - x + 5 = \sum_{k=0}^3 c_{k+1} x^k \in V \\
c = (5, -1, 0, 2)^T \in \mathbb{R}^4
$$
or another example
$$
p(x) = 1 \\
c = (1,0,0,0)^T = e_1
$$
we have the differentiation operator $d/dx$ acting on the coordinates as
$$
D : \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}^n
$$
with matrix representation
$$
D = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dotsb & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & & 0 \\
\vdots & & & & & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dotsb & n \\
\end{pmatrix}
\quad (*)
$$
e.g.
$$
n = 3 \\
D =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
\\
D \, (2x^3-x+5) = D \, (5, -1, 0, 2)^T = (-1, 0, 6)^T = 6 x^2 - 1
$$

Then we can infer from $(*)$
$$
\ker D = \{ c e_1 \mid c \in \mathbb{R} \}
$$
which consists of all constant polynomials, a one dimensional subspace of $V$, and
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{img}{img}
\img D = \mathbb{R}^n
$$
which are the polynomials of maximal degree $n$.

Comment: what is e(p)=c?

Comment: It is a bijection between polynomials and coordinates.

Comment: You can skip the coordinate representations, and just think in terms of the polynomials, maybe invoking the rank-nullity theorem, that is the essence of DonAntonio's comment/hint above.